# Cannot find the Field for the object

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, runtime-error

I seem to have an issue with Eclipse. I have three variables that I have declared within a method. When I go to debug through the program, these variables don't have a value. When I inspect the right side of the equation (pulling a field from a data table), the information is correct. However, the variable is never set. When I inspect the variable it says "Cannot find the field for the object exampleControllers.java". I have tried globally declaring the variable, declaring within the method, declaring within a different method etc. etc.

The other thing I have noticed is that my debugger seems to go out of sync pretty often on this particular java file. It will sync up correctly for a bit and then desync for several runs. No matter what I do (clean, refresh, rebuild) it continues to desync. I was wondering if that might have something to do with it.

Below is the source code:

```
    miles = Integer.parseInt(programName.dataStructure.getData("miles"));
    days = Integer.parseInt(programName.dataStructure.getData("days"));
    annualMiles = ((miles * 2) *days * 52);
```

[Error Message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzdn4.png)

Edit:

```
public class Program {
    public int miles = 0;
    public int days = 0;
    public int annualMiles = 0;

   method1() {}

   public final void method2(final int variable, final HttpServletRequest variable2) {
       switch (variable) {
           case screen1:
               code; 
               if(programName.dataStructure(variable3)) {
                  miles = Integer.parseInt(programName.dataStructure.getData("miles");
                  days = Integer.parseInt(programName.dataStructure.getData("days");
                  annualMiles = ((miles * 2) * days * 52);

              }
          }
```

Comment: Hard to say without more code.  Are you actually declaring the fields anywhere?  In other words, what you have here is a variable name without a declaration.  Unlike Python, Java is a strongly typed language.  You either need something like "int miles;" earlier in your code or you need to change this line to be like this: "int miles = Integer..."

Comment: I have it declared globally so : public int miles = 0; public int days = 0; public int annualMiles = 0;

Comment: Also most of the rest of the code is company specific, so I'm hesitant in posting. All I've added to the java file is what you see there in the original post.

Comment: But where are you declaring it?  Can you reproduce the problem without the company specific code?  Does the code compile and just not run?

Comment: This question needs more code. Where are the variables declared? How are they accessed? (inherited,...)

Comment: You must have added more than those three lines; you said so yourself.  You also added the declarations.

Comment: No the problem only happens on this one java file. Everywhere else the debugger works fine. So yes I supposed I added 6 lines, declaring the three variables and then defining them.

Comment: Well, without more code I won't be able to help because it's impossible to tell what the problem is with just the three lines you've provided.

Comment: Which is why I'm stuck, the program works fine and runs correctly. Its just that when Im in the debugger it says these fields cannot be found.

Comment: Does it actually complain about `programName.dataStructure.getData("days")` (and the miles one)?

Comment: No just that when I'm debugging through it, days miles and annualMiles won't have a value. The right side of the equation (programName.dataStructure.getData("days)) when inspected has the correct value.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce the error with this code snippet.. I tried to reconstruct a working code out of the snippet and mine doesn't fail when debugging.